# dynamicaly calling variables with strings vb.net

Tags: vb.net, variables, dynamic

my problem is that i need to make the example below work

```
dim player, p1cards, p2cards, ..., p6cards as integer
p1cards = 3
p2cards = 6
...
for i as integer = 1 to 6
  if ("p" & player & "cards") < 5 then
     player+=1
    "blah"
  end if
next
```

However if ("p" & player & "cards") < 5 then does nothing what was expected. Is there a way to make ("p" & player & "cards") basically the variable so that it can check it quickly and easily

Comment: so..A complete and clear question?

Comment: Use a select case for each integer.

Comment: Instead of individual variables, you need to store your values in a different data structure that you can then loop or enumerate through. Like an array or list. If you truly need to build a "unique key" arbitrarily, you can use a hash table or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can use something called [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    dict.Add("p1cards", 3)
    dict.Add("p2cards", 4)
    dict.Add("p3cards", 5)
    dict.Add("p4cards", 6)
    dict.Add("p5cards", 7)
    dict.Add("p6cards", 8)

    For Each item In dict
        If item.Value < 5 Then
            Dim aString As String = item.Key
            'do what u wan
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [List(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store more info about the player (i.e. player name / number of cards).

```
Dim Player As New List(Of Object())

'initialization
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    Player.Add(New Object() {"Player " & i + 1, 0}) 'player name / number of cards
Next i

Player(0)(1) = 3 'player 1 cards: 3
Player(1)(1) = 6 'player 2 cards: 6

'test
For i As Integer = 0 To Player.Count - 1

    Dim strName As String = Player(i)(0)
    Dim intCards As String = CInt(Player(i)(1))

    If intCards < 5 Then MsgBox(strName & " - blah")

Next i
```